# Cascading dropdown with Static data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

i need to develop two dropdown list in my MVC3 project, where first dropdown will be a db driven and based on the data selected on first dropdown my second dropdown should change. Second dropdown is having hard coded text and value. how could i achived this. please help

```
Following is my codebased

viewmodel

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductTypeCode{ get; set; }
public int? ProductID { get; set; }


public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductGroupCode;
public int? ProductGrpID { get; set; }

Controller

public ActionResult Index()     {         
var model = new MyViewModel         
{             
// TODO: Fetch those from your repository ,
model.ProductTypeCode= new SelectList(obj.ProductTypeCode as                   System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "DispalyText");
return view(model);

}

VIEW


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductID , Model.ProductTypeCode, "ALL" , new { @class = "DropDownList" })</td>
```

My question is based on the above dropdown of productType, i need to populate another dropdown called "ProductGroup" which is having hardcoded value. based on the ProductType dropdown the value of productgroup should change.

Comment: You should share what you have tried already such as sample code. Else no one knows where to really direct you aside to more online references.  For more specific help and troubleshooting your code, provide examples.

Comment: Do you have any code to provide?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. You can write your own javascript to handle the onchange event.  There are literally thousands of simple tutorials on this exact topic.  [This one](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Creating-a-Cascading-Dropdown-in-ASPnet-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx) will probably address your question the best.
2. You can use [extensions like Telerik's.](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/cascadingcombobox)  They're relatively straight forward, well documented, but do have the extra weight of another library on them (although the markup they generate is pretty slim).

If you go with option 1 and write your own, the two main things you'll have to add in will be an extra controller action and some javascript.

The javascript will listen for change events on your product Id drop down.  Put this in a document ready function on the page itself.

```
$("#ProductID").change(function() {

    // Get the product id selected
    var id = $(this).val();

    // Fire off an ajax request to get the groups
    $.ajax({
        // whatever the url may be.
        url: "@Url.Action("Groups")" + id, // Append the id to the url.
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Id+ "\">" + item.Name + "</option>";
            });

            // Set the secondary dropdown content to the newly created
            // list of options.  Use whatever Id your secondary is.
            $("#ProductGroup").html(items);
    });
```

The controller action responds to the ajax call with the list of appropriate product groups.

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Groups(int id)
    {
        // You only need the id and a name field in the response, not the
        // entire object.
        var groups = _myService.FindGroupsForProductId(id)
            .Select(g => new 
            {
                Id = g.Id, 
                Name = g.Name
            });

        // Return a json result.  You only need to re
        return Json(groups);
    }
}
```

The code above should help you get started.  It's assuming several things that you didn't show in your code at all.  Your question got downvoted because at first, you didn't post any code.  Then, the code that you did post doesn't really show that you've put any effort into finding the solution on your own.  Find some jquery tutorials on this, there are thousands, then if you have specific problems, bring them here.